# Equivalent regex pattern from c# to javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

Convertion of the regular expression from C# to javascript.

C#

```
(?<![\\]);
```

Javascript

```
/(?<![\\]);/
```

While using Regex.split, the regular expression for C# works fine but in javascript 'Unexcpected Quantifier' error occurs.

string

```
"CN=s\,tttrrr,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local;CN=g\;hi\,klm,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local;CN=rrr\ttt,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local;CN=Vvvv,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local"
```

Result

```
CN=s\,tttrrr,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local
CN=g\;hi\,klm,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local
CN=rrr\ttt,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local
CN=Vvvv,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local
```

Comment: js won't support lookbehinds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting the input based on `;` which was preceded by a word boundary will give you the desired output.

```
> var str = "CN=s\\,tttrrr,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local;CN=g\\;hi\\,klm,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local;CN=rrr\ttt,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local;CN=Vvvv,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local"
undefined
> str.split(/\b;/g)
[ 'CN=s\\,tttrrr,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local',
  'CN=g\\;hi\\,klm,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local',
  'CN=rrr\ttt,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local',
  'CN=Vvvv,OU=OU1,DC=dom1,DC=local' ]
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wT0zZ8/6)